# IBM Lotus Notes 5.0.9 - Creating a custom mobile app

Tags: xpages

One of our customers have Lotus Notes version 5.0.9. They wanted to check if it's possible to create an android mobile application to connect to the backend for documents workflow.

Couldn't find much resources about this scenario for this version. I believe Domino is already available on that version - so is Xpages a viable solution for that scenario? Thanks.

Comment: You can make native Android application, and use Domino R5 as data source via web services or REST.

Comment: Frantisek: no Webservice in 5.x and Rest only to read view entries as XML or Java 1.1 Agents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPages are available since IBM Notes Version 8.5. The term "Domino" stands for the IBM Notes server. So if your customer has Notes version 5.0.9 they probably have Domino version 5.0.9 too (although one can mix Notes and Domino versions).

Therefore XPages are no option for your, apart from the fact you could install a second Domino sever with version 9.0 just to host the xpages.

Answer (score 7):

XPages requires at least Domino 8.5.x (and preferably Domino 9.0 which is the latest IBM Domino release). So you need to upgrade the Domino server if you want to use XPages.

FYI: Notes 5 was released in 1999 (see [the history of IBM Notes on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Notes#History)).

Comment: The official end of support date for version 5 was 30 September 2005. Software vendors release new versions for a reason... your customer should consider upgrading to a version that wasn't distributed via floppy disks.

Answer (score 0):

If they are on R5 what are they using for a workflow engine? If they are using a database designed from Approval.ntf (I think R5 was the last time it was shipped with the product) then it is a very old and very difficult to maintain &/or modify. If so then they probably need to take a deep breath and upgrade and re-design. Can probably cobble something together to make it work but really question the wisdom of doing that.